# Numpy np.dot() on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is an easy question, but I'm getting confused by the size involved.

Using NumPy, I have a 3-dimensional array, shape = (10, 100, 100).

(The way I think of it is as an np.ndarray of 10 "matrices", each shaped 100 by 100, i.e.

```
arr1 = [M1 M2 M3....M10]
```

where `M1.shape = (100,100), M2.shape = (100,100),...`

I also have a second array of data called "arrB", which is `arrB.shaped (100,)`. My goal is to do matrix multiplication with these numpy arrays, i.e. `(arrB.T)*arr1*(arrB)`, resulting in a single integer. Using numpy arrays, this operation should be completed with `np.dot()`

```
op1 = np.dot(arr1, arrB)
op2 = np.dot((arrB.T), op1)
```

or

```
endproduct = np.dot((arrB.T), np.dot(arr1, arrB) )
```

However, this does not work. I get an error:

```
ValueError: shapes (100,) and (10,100) not aligned: 100 (dim 0) != 10 (dim 0)
```

If I do the operation on one "matrix" M# at a time, I can perform this operation, i.e.

```
element1 = arr1[0]
end = np.dot((arrB.T), np.dot(element1, arrB) )
```

Without splicing my original array, doing the operations, and appending again, how can I perform these operations on my original array `arr1` to result in

```
result = [(arrB.T)*arr1[0]*(arrB) (arrB.T)*arr1[1]*(arrB) (arrB.T)*arr1[2]*(arrB) ... 
                                                ....(arrB.T)*arr1[9]*(arrB) ]
```

Comment: I think a list comprehension can help you solve your problem.

Comment: @gabra I had a similar thought, but I don't have the correct expression. I was thinking something like:
`result = [ np.dot( (arrB.T), np.dot(arr1[i], arrB) ) for i in arr1[i] ]`
Unfortunately I get an Index Error.

Comment: @gabra What exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: Something like: `[arrB.T*arr1[n]*arrB for n in range(9)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this as -

```
arr3 = np.array([np.dot(arr2.T , np.dot(arr1[i] , arr2)) for i in range(arr1.shape[0])])
```

Answer (score 5):

With `arrB`, shape (100,), `.T` does nothing.  It needs to be `(1,100)` if you want `.T` to turn it into a `(100,1)` array.

In any case, to do the double dot with a (100,100) element you don't need `.T`.  Try:

```
np.dot(arrB, np.dot(element1, arrB) )
```

With only 10 'elements', the list comprehension or iterative method isn't bad:

```
out = np.empty((10,))
for i in range(10):
   out[i] = np.dot(arrB, np.dot(arrA[i], arrB))
```

or using a comprehension:

```
np.array([np.dot(arrB,np.dot(elmt,arrB)) for elmt in arrA] )
```

`np.einsum` is another option:

```
np.einsum('i,kij,j->k',arrB, arrA, arrB)
```

`np.tensordot` is also designed to work with 3d arrays.  It reshapes and transposes its inputs, so they become 2d arrays that `np.dot` can use.

```
np.dot(np.tensordot(arrA,arrB,[(2,),(0,)]),arrB) # needs more testing
```

You'll have to do some timings with realistic arrays to determine which is most efficient (and readable) for you.