# Broadcastable Numpy dot

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix-multiplication, blas

I have an array H of dimensions (n0, n2) and an array W of dimensions (n0, n1, n2, n3) and I want to do the following operation:

```
(H[:, None, :, None] * W).sum(axis=(0, 2))
```

As far as I know, the above line does not use BLAS libraries. Is there a way to use `numpy.dot` or a similar function that uses BLAS to do the same computation (and still without copying the array H several times in memory)?

Answer (score 1):

You have identified one way of doing this; I know of two others.

For a small example

```
In [365]: n0,n1,n2,n3=2,3,4,5
In [366]: H=np.ones((n0,n2));W=np.ones((n0,n1,n2,n3))
```

comparative times are:

```
In [362]: timeit np.tensordot(H,W,[(0,1),(0,2)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.8 µs per loop

In [363]: timeit np.einsum('ik,ijkl',H,W)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop

In [364]: timeit (H[:,None,:,None]*W).sum(axis=(0,2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 µs per loop
```

`tensordot` reshapes and transposes the inputs so it can call `np.dot`.  `einsum` decodes the string, and does its own `nditer` in C.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129207/901925 has timings for another multidimensional `dot`, involving `(100,)*(10,100,100)*(100,)` arrays.