# np.dot() with Python broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays, one shaped (3000,) and the other is an array of twenty 3000 by 3000 matrices, i.e. shape (20, 3000, 3000)

```
first.shape = (3000,)
second.shape = (20, 3000, 3000)
```

I being doing a numpy dot product.

```
import numpy as np
dotprod1 = np.dot( second, first)
```

this works, and the output `dotprod1` is an array shaped (20, 3000).

But what if I wish to take the dot product again?

```
dotprod2 = np.dot( first, dotprod1)
```

This gives an error.

```
ValueError: shapes (3000,) and (20,3000) not aligned: 3000 (dim 0) != 20 (dim 0)
```

I would like to have an output of 20 values. How does one use broadcasting to do this?

Comment: same question but with a `(10,100,100)` array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128883/numpy-np-dot-on-multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 3):

`dotprod2 = np.dot( first, dotprod1)` fails because `first` is of shape `(3000, )` and `dotprod1` is of shape `(20, 3000)`, swap them and the error will go (if that's your intention):

```
dotprod2 = np.dot(dotprod1, first)
```

besides, you can also use `np.ndarray.dot` to make the semantics clear:

```
dotprod2 = dotprod1.dot(first)
```

Comment: Note that this is not the correct answer if you want to do "matrix multiplication" with numpy arrays

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, a **matrix** must be of `ndim` == **2**, in your case (some array's `ndim`>2), the general solution is exactly *dot product of two arrays*. What do you mean by **correct** in your definition? You can also check the docs of `np.dot`: *For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication*.

Comment: What I meant by matrix multiplication is that one array should be transposed. 
For matrices, the operation should be two arrays shaped (1,3000) and (3000,1) and one matrix, (3000,3000).

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, idk what's your exact intention... could you elaborate why `np.dot(dotprod1, first)` is **incorrect** (ain't it of shape `(20, )`?) and what's your expected output using a simpler code demo? Moreover, (1,3000)*(3000,1) is (1,1), not (3000, 3000)